# X Session / xdmx, keybindings lost

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

I am using startx (with Xdmx) to run a remote session on another computer.  However,  when I do this,  keybindings (especially control,  alt and the cursor keys) are not correct on the remote session-- and this persists when the session is closed,  requiring logout to restore.

I'm coming up zilch after some googling.  Any ideas?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the remote server remaps the keys - most of the time caused by a xmodmap setup which not considers thet different clients may have different needs.

Where the settings are stored/applied depends on your environment (plain X / Gnome / KDE / CDE / etc.).

Comment: Some success from exporting xmodmap before startx and then reloading:  only works effectively so far when starting from the same environment (ie, xfce to xfce,  not KDE/ubuntu/etc to another environment.

Suspect closer examination of the mapping may fix.  Thanks.